# parsing a txt file in c++

Tags: c++

Hi I'm coming from C# and have been working with c++ alot lately and I need help,
I have a text file(500mb) that i need to load into an array(matrix).
the format on the text file is

```
specimen  date      result
E1       111111    0.5
```

How can i just extract out the result of this and put only that into my matrix where each column would represent a different specimen? I know in C# i could eaisly parse this but i dont know how to do it in c++
thank you for your help ,i just want to know the commands or functions that I would need to know

```
                 E1 ............En
result@ time 1   .................
                 .               .
                 . . .  . . . . ..
result@time n    .................
```

there are 7000 specimens , and 3 years worth of dates , the results range from 0.1 to 20000

Comment: Is this C or C++?  The answers are _VERY_ different.

Comment: Does `date` have to be parsed like a date or it is just a number/string of text?

Comment: Is this homework?  If so, add the homework tag

Comment: its a research project and its my first time using c++ or anything that involves a super computer , Iwould link this with a database myself but there are none on the computers,

Comment: and i just need to get rid of the data and specimen and make a matrix like where the first column and row would be the result of specimen 1 and time 1 and

Comment: Wait, what goes where?  The `Date` is a column?

Comment: Can we assume there is a one line title followed by multiple lines of data. Are there guaranteed to be no spaces in "Specimen" and "data"? Are there guaranteed to be exactly three values on every line?

Comment: i added some more stuff i might be able to figure it out with what people wrote people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Define how to read and parse one line from your file.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

struct Data
{
    double value;
    operator double() const {return value;}
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, Data& d)
    {
        static std::string  specimen; // Assume specimen has no spaces it in.
        static std::string  date;     // Treat the date as a string as it probably has '/'

        std::string  line;
        // Read and process each line independently (hopefully compensating for errors). 
        std::getline(stream, line);
        std::stringstream   linestream(line);

        // Read and ingore the first two items. Then save the value.
        linestream >> specimen >> date >> d.value;
        return stream;
    }
};
```

#### Now just read the file into the vector.

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream          file("data.file");
    std::vector<double>    data;

    // Ignore the header line.
    file.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    // Copy the data from the file into the vector.
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<Data>(file),
              std::istream_iterator<Data>(),
              std::back_inserter(data)
             );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use file streams from the standard library, and formatted input:

```
std::vector< double > results;

std::ifstream input( "yourfile.txt" );
std::string specimen;
int date;
double result;

while( ( input >> specimen >> date >> result ) )
{
    ... do something with result ...
    results.push_back( result );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use flex and bison:

http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.16/16.07/UsingFlexandBison/index.html

Or [Boost::regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html)

Here's an example I did recently in Boost::regex

https://github.com/homer6/import-geoip-data

Comment: That's overkill for simple text parsing.

Comment: Maybe he wants to build upon it. And maybe he has data that could contain errors and he wants validate at the same time. I don't know; I'm just giving him options.

Comment: this is really nice too but it is overkill , I may use this in the future thou thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef std::string specimen;
typedef std::string date;
typedef std::pair<specimen, date> sample;

std::map<sample, double> data;

void parse(std::istream& in) {
    sample t;
    double result
    in.ignore(1024, '\n'); //skip the title line
    while(in >> t.first>> t.second>> result)
        data[t] = result;
}
```